# How to write join query for windows azure

Tags: azure

I am new to windows azure. Please Help me out.

how should I write this query :

```
"SELECT catchup.*,news.text from catchup,news where news.deviceID = catchup.deviceID AND news.name = '$name' ORDER BY id DESC";
```

I used this format to write it

```
mssql.query('SELECT t.text, t.complete, p.description FROM ToDoItem as t INNER JOIN Priority as p ON t.priority = p.number', {
        success: function(results) {
            console.log(results);
        },
        error: function(err) {
            console.log("error is: " + err);
    });
```

but its giving error code 500. Also how to pass the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

```
var sql = "SELECT t.text, t.complete, p.description FROM ToDoItem as t INNER JOIN Priority as p ON t.priority = p.number AND t.text = ?";
var name = '$name';

mssql.query(sql, [name], {
      success: function(results) {
         console.log(results);
      },
      error: function(err) {
                console.log("error is: " + err);
      }
   });
```

Comment: hey Thiago!!! thanx for the help,but still it shows the error Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1000 "bad URL" UserInfo=0x1f57dae0 {NSLocalizedDescription=bad URL, NSUnderlyingError=0x1e5e1680 "bad URL", com.Microsoft.WindowsAzureMobileServices.ErrorRequestKey=<NSMutableURLRequest (null)>}

Comment: connect to your sql database from your local Sql Server Management Studio and perform the query your are creating and see if it works